# Change a value of existing class with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to change the value of a property of an existing CSS class using vanilla JavaScript?

To elaborate, I have a button item in a form, that is styled purely with CSS file. Is there a way to modify the class that applies the style to the item using vanilla JavaScript?

Or should I create a separate class and replace the currently applied class? I think this second option would be the cleanest way, but I was wonder if the first way is actually possible.

Comment: How a about a third option: Add an *additional* class that extends/overwrites the styling of the existing class. Depending on the use case, that might be preferable.

Comment: I have been trying this, but it doesn't seem to be working for me, something I Should of clarified is that I only want to change the appearance on hover and active. I have made a main class for the basic stuff, and then a sub-class(?) I'm not sure if that is what its called, to change the background and shadow on hover and on active, but it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: `.buttonTool {
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select: none;

 border-radius: 1.5rem;
 padding-bottom: 1rem;
 vertical-align: middle;

 transition: 1s;
}

 .buttonTool .defaultTheme:hover {
  transform: scale(1.015);
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(330deg, #dbe6e6, #ffffff);
  box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px #8f999f,
               -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
 }

 .buttonTool .defaultTheme:active {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(145deg,  #dbe6e6, #ffffff);
 }`

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nxrma4t8/1/

Here you can see it's not working, but if you remove the .defaultTheme from the active and hover state, it works fine.

EDIT: I removed the space between the classes in CSS, and it works... It's always the dumb things that I don't see

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) attribute

Example `document.getElementById('someElement').style.color ='red'`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want to make a change in a CSS class itself not to change CSS properties of an element.
It is not possible to do so.

You can either change an element class or component styling via an `element.style` property